# 'dvisvgm' doesn't detect 'libgs' with MacTex 2023 and 'libgs' installed - MacOS 12.7.2 (Monterey)

Tags: mactex, ghostscript, dvisvgm

I want to convert my LaTeX file using package 'tikz' into a HTML file using 'make4ht', which itself runs 'dvisvgm', which itself needs 'libgs'. Everything should run automatically as given by [auto-detection of libgs on recent macOS](https://github.com/mgieseki/dvisvgm/issues/197).

Checking 'dvisvgm -V1' returns no Ghostscript support:

```
dvisvgm 3.0.3 (x86_64-apple-darwin18.7.0)
-----------------------------------------
brotli:   1.0.9
clipper:  6.2.1
freetype: 2.13.0
kpathsea: 6.3.5
potrace:  1.16
xxhash:   0.8.1
zlib:     1.2.13
```

I have checked, that there is a symbolic link ('/usr/local/lib/libgs.10.dylib') pointing to '/usr/local/share/ghostscript/10.00.0/lib/libgs.dylib.10.00'.

Also trying setting 'LIBGS' or '--libgs' to '/usr/local/share/ghostscript/10.00.0/lib/libgs.dylib.10.00' doesn't change the behavior. I don't believe that the MacTex package is faulty, however could it be that on of the latest MacOS updates has change something? Any experience out there?

I tried several ways to feed the 'libgs' Library to 'dvisvgm' without success.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE!

Comment: It will not help you but on my old macos I have ``export LIBGS=/opt/local/lib/libgs.dylib`` in my ``.bash_profile`` (because I installed gs 9.54 from MacPorts) and I use the dvisvgm from darwin-legacy and it is at version 3.0.3 and reports support for Ghostscript. Have you checked *Why is dvisvgm’s PostScript support disabled on my machine* at https://dvisvgm.de/FAQ/

Comment: `dvisvgm -h` lists option `--libgs`but it seems that `dvisvgm` doesn't like the install `libgs` library.

Answer (score 2):

I solved it in the way that I installed `Ghostscript` from `MacPorts`. Now it works:

```
dvisvgm -V1 --libgs=/opt/local/lib/libgs.dylib
dvisvgm 3.0.3 (x86_64-apple-darwin18.7.0)
-----------------------------------------
brotli:      1.0.9
clipper:     6.2.1
freetype:    2.13.0
Ghostscript: 10.2.1
kpathsea:    6.3.5
potrace:     1.16
xxhash:      0.8.1
zlib:        1.2.13
```

Thank you!